# Python get pdf response from a page

Tags: php, python, pdf, response

there is a web page that returns a PDF once a form is submitted (post).

I guess that the pdf is being generated on the go as if i enter incorrect values in the form i get a blank pdf.

i wish to understand how this is being done.

My second question is :

How do i capture this pdf as incoming in python.

i tried this :

```
r = session.post('https://myweb.mypage.php',headers=headers,data=pay2,verify=False)

print r
```

i get the output :

however i need to capture the pdf that has been generated as if i post form in the web page, the pdf is downloaded automatically.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was not properly researched:

I tried accessing the r.text to find an answer however could not get it.

so this worked for me:

r = session.post('https://mysite.com/mypage.php',headers=headers,data=pay2,verify=False)

f = open('11.pdf', 'w')

f.write(r.content)